# Doctrine2: Cannot find concurrently persisted entity with findById

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have the current setup:

A regular Symfony2 web request can create and persist `Job` entity which also creates a [Gearman](http://gearman.org) Job, lets say this occurs in `process 1`. The Gearman Job is executed by a Gearman Worker which is passed the `Job` entity's `ID`.

I also use Symfony to create a Gearman Worker, this is run as a PHP CLI process, lets call this `process 2`.

For those not familiar with Gearman the worker code operates something like so:

```
for loop 5 times
    get job from gearman (blocking method call)
    get job entity from database
    do stuff
```

Essentially this code keeps a Symfony2 instance running to handle 5 Jobs before the worker dies.

My issue is this: On the first job that the worker handles Doctrine2 is able to retrieve the created job from the database without issue using the following code:

```
$job = $this->doctrine
            ->getRepository('AcmeJobBundle:Job')
            ->findOneById($job->workload()); // workload is the job id
```

However, once this job completes and the for loop increments to wait for a second job, lets say this arrives from another Symfony2 web request on `process 3` creating the `Job` with `ID` 2, the call to the Doctrine2 repository returns null even though the entity is definitely in the database.

Restarting the worker solves the issue, so when it carries out it's first loop it can pick up `Job` 2.

Does anyone know why this happens? Does the first call of `getRepository` or `findOneById` do some sort of table caching from MySQL that doesn't allow it to see the subsequently added `Job` 2?

Does MySQL only show a snapshot of the DB to a given connection as long as it is held open?

I've also tried resetting the `entityManager` before making the second call to `findOneBy` to no avail.

Thanks for any advice in advance, this one is really stumping me.

**Update:**

I've created a single process test case to rule out whether or not it was the concurrency causing the problem, and the test case executes as expected. It seems the only time the repository can't find job 2 is when it is added to the DB on another process.

```
    // Job 1 already exists
    $job = $this->doctrine
    ->getRepository('AcmeJobBundle:Job')
    ->findOneById(1);

    $job->getId(); // this is fine.

    $em->persist(new Job()); // creates job 2

    $em->flush();

    $job = $this->doctrine
    ->getRepository('AcmeJobBundle:Job')
    ->findOneById(2);

    $job->getId(); // this is fine too, no exception.
```

Comment: not sure if this helps, but $dm->clear(); after the $dm->flush(); might do the trick.
Experienced a similar behavior, when i was storing several objects in a row, but wasn't able to query for 'em within the same request. 

Was pointed to the clear() Method later, but didn't try it with the codesnippet to be honest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot in a bit and report back if it works. Every bit of info helps.

Comment: Sadly clearing the entity manager didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did some testing to see if doctrine works fine adding and searching for `Jobs` in the same process and it seems to work fine like that.

Comment: You'll pardon my ignorance of gearman, but that code looks like you maybe are instancing 5 versions of symfony at once.  But you should really post your controller to get better help.

Comment: That's correct, 5 instances of Symfony at once, each handling 5 jobs before the instance refreshes. Also there is no controller, the question was making use of Symfony command line commands - but really I was just wondering what was going on database wise that meant one instance of Symfony wasn't seeing changes made in another concurrent instance given that the database was being flushed. Since writing this question I've re-written the workers using PDO since I could run more workers with better scalability than instancing Symfony - less memory per worker. Thanks for the help none the less.

Comment: as an aside, use find() when using the primary key as the search criteria, rather than findOneById()

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one process tries to load entity before it has saved by the second process.

Doctrine caches loaded entities by their id, so that when you get a second request for the same object it loads without making another query to the database. You can reed more about Doctrine IdentityMap [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)